# error: disk 'hd0,gpt3' not found

Tags: boot

I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed on zfs dual boot with Windows.

I upgraded to 22.04.

Now I have this error:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair I only use ext4, but seeing issues on upgrades using anything else, RAID, btrfs, zfs, etc. I think grub is not correctly updated. Part of why I prefer new install & restore from backup. Also then tests that you know how to restore backup when (not if) drive fails in future. Drives are more reliable now, but.

Comment: Here is the pastebin link: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/qzqGhKY2J8/

Comment: Do not know zfs.  You do have two different Ubuntu UEFI boot entries in UEFI. Have you tried both. Is system set to boot in UEFI mode? You have an old BIOS boot grub in MBR of sda that is invalid & error message may be from that. UUID shown in your error message does not seem to exist.

Comment: The other UEFI boot entry worked! I have deleted the other vfat partition but not sure how to remove the old BIOS boot grub in MBR of sda. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: We typically do not recommend removing grub from MBR. It can be erased with dd, but dd is also known as Data Destroyer. Any typo totally damages data. You just need to remember not to try to boot in BIOS mode.